# Funciones void en c# en que casos debo aplicarla

Tags: c#

En que casos debo usar una funcion void?
Porque tengo entendido que si no devuelve una respuesta al main es void... pero no entiendo en que casos aplicarla y en cuales no. Lo decido yo? Tiene alguna regla de aplicacion?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: **Hola Elektrajim** -El void significa "vacío". Este método consiste en que se ejecutara un bloque de código si devolver nada. O sea, es en pocas palabras, un procedimiento por el cual no devuelve un valor. Simplemente lo procesa. Por ejemplo, *imagínate inflar las ruedas de un automóvil. Se ejecuta el proceso pero este no devuelve nada, simplemente infla las ruedas del automóvil.*

Answer (score 3):

**(Todo método declara un cuerpo en cuyo interior lleva código que ejecutará cuando se llame al método, pero los métodos `void` NO retornan valor alguno a diferencia de los demás `int`, `double`, `bool`, `char`, `string` que si lo hacen)**

Bien, primero que todo y antes que nada, debes entender un poco sobre que son y como se usan los **métodos**.

> **¿Que es un método?**
>
> Explicado con mis propias palabras, los métodos son los miembros de las clases que permiten llamar bloques de código **(es decir que declaran un cuerpo con código en su interior y que al llamarlos se ejecuta ese código)** aparte del [constructor de la clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

```
public void Metodo(parametro 1, parametro 2, parametro N)
{
    //Cuerpo del método
}
```

**Todo método ejecutará el código que tenga en su cuerpo**, pero no todos los métodos son iguales... existen los métodos que retornan un valor:

```
int MetodoA()...
bool MetodoB()...
string MetodoC()...
char MetodoD()...
object MetodoZ()...
```

Todos estos requieren que se use la palabra clave `return` dentro de su cuerpo (y al final de todo el código dentro del cuerpo) para indicar que valor va a retornar este método.

En la otra cara de la moneda tenemos a los métodos vacíos, los `void`, que como su nombre indica, no retornan valor alguno. Los void también llevan código dentro de sus cuerpos, pero **no retornan valor alguno**

```
void MetodoVacio()...
```

Dicho esto, te pondré un ejemplo:

Por ejemplo, tienes una clase llamada `MiClase` que contiene varios métodos...

```
public class MiClase
{
   public MiClase(Puedes poner parametros, si quieres ya que no es obligatorio)
   {
      //Este es el constructor de la clase, aquí
      //puedes poner código que se ejecutará al instanciar a la clase
   }

   public void MetodoVacio(Puedes poner parametros, si quieres ya que no es obligatorio)
   {
      //Este es un método que NO retorna valor alguno, puedes poner
      //código en su cuerpo o no, pero nunca podrá retornar valores;
      //curiosamente, si puedes usar return dentro de este tipo de método
      //pero NO podrás indicar un valor que retornar

      return; 
   }

   public int MetodoEntero(Puedes poner parametros, si quieres ya que no es obligatorio)
   {
       //Este es un método que retorna un valor entero, puedes poner
       //código en su cuerpo o no, pero siempre tendrá que retornar
       //un valor entero, en este caso he puesto 27

       return 27;
   }

   public string MetodoString(Puedes poner parametros, si quieres ya que no es obligatorio)
   {
       //Este es un método que retorna una cadena de texto, puedes poner
       //código en su cuerpo o no, pero siempre tendrá que retornar
       //un valor string, en este caso he puesto Hola Mundo

       return "Hola Mundo";
   }

   public char MetodoCaracter(Puedes poner parametros, si quieres ya que no es obligatorio)
   {
       //Este es un método que retorna un caracter, puedes poner
       //código en su cuerpo o no, pero siempre tendrá que retornar
       //un caracter, en este caso he puesto el caracter A

       return 'A';
   }

   //Y así sucesivamente

}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Hola Elektrajim**

-El void significa "vacío". Este método consiste en que se ejecutara un bloque de código si devolver nada. O sea, es en pocas palabras, un procedimiento por el cual no devuelve un valor. Simplemente lo procesa.

Por ejemplo, *imagínate inflar las ruedas de un automóvil. Se ejecuta el proceso pero este no devuelve nada, simplemente infla las ruedas del automóvil.*